# Como puedo poner dos columnas en el responsive de bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

estoy usando bootstrap para acomodar las imágenes en responsive.
Cuando aplico la clase img-responsive a las imágenes, en escritorio se acomodan de a 4 pero en móvil de a 1.

Me gustaría saber como puedo modificar la librería de bootstrap o como se le da una condicional para que cuando sea móvil se muestren
Código con el que llamo la clase

```
 <img class="img-responsive" alt="image description" src="'.$imageurl.'">
```

Clase Css

```
 .img-responsive {
display: block;
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
img {
display: block;
width: 100%;
}
img {
max-width: 100%;
height: auto;
}
img {
vertical-align: middle;
} 
img {
border: 0;
}
 *   {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
}
style attribute {
visibility: visible;
animation-delay: 0.4s;
animation-name: fadeInUp;
}
```

Comment: Me encantaría ayudarte, pero no termino de entender. El título de la pregunta dice una cosa y luego preguntas otra, además esta última no se entiende ¿qué quieres decir con que "cuando sea móvil se muestren Código con el que llamo la clase"?

Comment: Revisa: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/layout/grid/

Comment: a las columnas que contienen las imágenes agrégales esta `class` `col-xs-6`

Answer (score 0):

No eres tan claro con lo que dices , pero imagino que cada imagen está dentro de div con class col-*. Si es así te recomiendo que busques Gris de Bootstrap por ejemplo col-md-4 col-lg-3